# MySQL OR statement output does not make sense

Tags: mysql

When trying this query:

```
SELECT * FROM superpart WHERE
Brick_subpart_id = 603 OR 145;
```

The output is then:

```
'200', '144'
'10002', '144'
'620', '145'
```

Why does the '144' shows up? I do not ask for a range between 603 and 145 right? Even so, 144 is lower then 145...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM superpart WHERE
Brick_subpart_id In( 603 , 145)
```

Comment: Thanks that works. Cant check off your answer just yet (7min remaining), but do you have any idea why my query gives those results?

Answer (score 6):

This is because you are not comparing 145 to anything, hence it becomes true, and your query matches all records.

The query should be

```
SELECT * FROM superpart WHERE
Brick_subpart_id = 603 OR Brick_subpart_id = 145;
```

It can be rewritten as:

```
SELECT * FROM superpart WHERE
Brick_subpart_id IN (603,145)
```